# Send Spring Form from AuthenticationFailureHandler to Controller and create BindingResult

Tags: spring-security

I am development user authentication with Spring Security.

I wanna get Spring Form parameters through @Valid annotation in my Controller method. First, Spring security is performed, then, I need know to send Login object from AuthenticationFailureHandler to Controller method.

After, in Controller method i need create BindingResult to emulate in jsp Spring Form errors functionality.

Now i have this code in AuthenticationFailureHandler and Controller method.

```
public class AuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Login login = new Login();

        login.setType(request.getParameter("type"));
        login.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        login.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

        request.setAttribute("login", login);

        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("./login/error"));
    }
}
```

In Controller method

```
@RequestMapping("/login/error")
public String loginError(Model model, @Valid Login login, BindingResult result) {

    String message = this.messageSource.getMessage(
            "NoAuth.loginManager",
            null,
            LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

    ObjectError error = new ObjectError("general", message);

    result.addError(error);

    model.addAttribute("login", new Login());

    return "home";
}
```

Comment: You are setting a request attribute and then performing a redirect, after which the attribute will be lost. You should probably explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve with the login data after the authentication failure.

Comment: I only want same Spring Form behaviour although Spring Security auth. I need send to method Controller same data that AuthenticationFailureHandler get from user call, thereby @Valid and BindingResult can found without problem. Now Login and BindingResult are null how we can expect.

Comment: I mean that you should edit your question to explain what you want to happen (in terms of your app, rather than Spring controllers). Spring Security doesn't use Spring MVC binding and, as a rule, errors when submitting a login form shouldn't be treated the same as normal validation errors, so it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.